# ARM template issue boot diagonistic not going to existing storage container

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have the following template , what I want to do is , I have enabled the boot diagonistics and want the bootdiagonistic to go to https://noltu.blob.core.windows.net/lalu which is an existing container.But I am getting the following error
The value of parameter bootDiagnostics.storageAccountUri is invalid.Below is the ARM template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "adminPassword": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "minLength": 12,
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "dnsLabelPrefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[toLower(concat(parameters('vmName'),'-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, parameters('vmName'))))]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIpName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "myPublicIP",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIPAllocationMethod": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Dynamic",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Dynamic",
          "Static"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Allocation method for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
      "publicIpSku": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Basic",
        "allowedValues": [
          "Basic",
          "Standard"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "SKU for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
        }
      },
     "blobStorageEndpoint":{
       "type":"string",
       "defaultValue": "blob.core.windows.net"

    },  
    "containerpoint":{
      "type":"string",
      "defaultValue": "lalu"

   },
     "newStorageAccountname":{
      "type":"string",
      "defaultvalue":"noltu"


     },
      "OSVersion": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "2019-Datacenter",
        "allowedValues": [
          "2008-R2-SP1",
          "2012-Datacenter",
          "2012-R2-Datacenter",
          "2016-Nano-Server",
          "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
          "2016-Datacenter",
          "2019-Datacenter",
          "2019-Datacenter-Core",
          "2019-Datacenter-Core-smalldisk",
          "2019-Datacenter-Core-with-Containers",
          "2019-Datacenter-Core-with-Containers-smalldisk",
          "2019-Datacenter-smalldisk",
          "2019-Datacenter-with-Containers",
          "2019-Datacenter-with-Containers-smalldisk"
        ],
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version."
        }
      },
      "vmSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard_D2_v3",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Size of the virtual machine."
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
      },
      "vmName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "simple-vm",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name of the virtual machine."
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      
      "nicName": "myVMNic",      
      "subnetName": "sub1",      
      "virtualNetworkName": "vnet3",
      "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]",
      "networkSecurityGroupName": "poni"
    },
    "resources": [
  
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('publicIPName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('publicIpSku')]"
        },
        "properties": {
          "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIPAllocationMethod')]",
          "dnsSettings": {
            "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
          }
        }
      },
      
   
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPName'))]",
          
        ],
        "properties": {
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "name": "ipconfig1",
              "properties": {
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "publicIPAddress": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPName'))]"
                },
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
          },
          "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
              "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
              "offer": "WindowsServer",
              "sku": "[parameters('OSVersion')]",
              "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
              "createOption": "FromImage",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
              }
            },
            "dataDisks": [
              {
                "diskSizeGB": 1023,
                "lun": 0,
                "createOption": "Empty"
              }
            ]
          },
          "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
              {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
              }
            ]
          },
          "diagnosticsProfile": {
            "bootDiagnostics": {
              "enabled": true,
              "storageUri": "[concat('http://',parameters('newStorageAccountname'),'.',parameters('blobStorageEndpoint'),'/',parameters('containerpoint'))]"
            
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "hostname": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPName')).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? Do you still work on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `storageUri` is used to set the Uri for the storage account, not for the special container. And it will create the container dynamcally. So the attribute `storageUri` should be like this:

```
"storageUri": "[concat('http://',parameters('newStorageAccountname'),'.',parameters('blobStorageEndpoint'),'/')]"
```

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?tabs=json#bootdiagnostics-object).